# Does XmlDocument.LoadXml append or replace?

Tags: c#, xml

In c#, if I have this

```
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<.....>");
doc.LoadXml("<.....>");
```

Does that 2nd one do a replace or append to the doc object?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: How would it even know that the XML documents would be compatible, and have the same structure, therefore, it would not append...

Answer (score 0):

[It](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) replaces. This is pretty obvious if you think about it and consider that valid XML documents must have a single root node.

More importantly, use [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), it is just better.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

...

var document = XDocument.Parse(...
```